# Cannot find iPadOS apps when search from a Mac

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, ios-appstore, mac-appstore

When using the Apple App Store app on my Mac, I cannot locate these two apps. Yet I can identify each app by their web page.

- *Gmail - Email by Google*
  Google LLC
  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gmail-email-by-google/id422689480
- *Proton Mail - Encrypted Email*
  Proton AG
  https://apps.apple.com/us/app/proton-mail-encrypted-email/id979659905?platform=ipad

My filters set in the App Store app are: *Price - Any*, *Category - Any*, and *Sort By - Relevance*.

Here is a screenshot of the Apple web page showing the app exists, and showing the App Store app failing to find that very same app.

[image]

My goal is to download the iPadOS app to run on my MacBook Air with [M1 chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1#M1). I have done just that with another iPad app. Yet with these two email apps I cannot find them in the App Store so I cannot download them to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Developers of apps can, and have opted out in this case of making their iPad/iPhone apps available for macOS. See: https://developer.apple.com/macos/iphone-and-ipad-apps/

You can see, for example, WolframAlpha Classic is marked available on. ARM Macs, iPad, iPhone, and iPod platforms.

[image: Screenshot of App Store page for WolframAlpha App]

However, Protonmail has been made unavailable on Mac platforms by its developers. The same is with the Gmail app.

[image: Screenshot of App Store page for Protonmail App]

There used to be a method to install custom apps on macOS, however, Apple has disabled this "feature" as of Big Sur 11.1. https://www.macrumors.com/2021/01/15/m1-macs-sideloading-ios-apps-no-longer-possible/

See also the last paragraph of this page, [*iPhone and iPad Apps, Now on Mac!*](https://apps.apple.com/us/story/id1535100517), at Apple.com:

> Most iPhone and iPad apps are compatible with a Mac with M1, but some may not be available because they require capabilities unique to iPhone or iPad. A developer may also choose to make their app unavailable on Mac.